# Создание кастомного дистрибутива Debian из настроенной системы

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование

Понимаю, тема достаточно заезжена, но не нашел ни одного стоящего мануала или документации для создания iso-образа из подготовленной системы, возможно, плохо смотрел.

Большинство ответов на stack-ресурсах указывает на использование [clonezilla](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19901/how-to-make-a-disk-image-and-restore-from-it-later).

[Документация clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php) также пошагового расписывает процесс создания образа и восстановление его через livecd-clonezilla.

Но я не пойму, чем этот способ отличается от того же зеркального копирования диска с помощью Acronis True Image. Мы используем стороннее ПО как для копирования, так и для восстановления.

Мы можем с помощью clonezilla создать iso-образ настроенной системы и без загрузки стороннего livecd использовать его для установки?

Какие есть альтернативы clonezillа? и способы создания образа системы?

Comment: исходить лучше из **конечной** цели: из того, что вы **в итоге** хотите со всем этим делать. хотя бы просто для того, чтобы избежать ситуации «микроскопом гвозди забиваем».

Comment: Могу сказать за клонзиллу - это не в ту степь. Она не умеет собирать исошники livecd.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin создать подготовленный дистрибутив без пользовательских файлов, который могу перенести на другую машину